# Extjs 4 GridPanel: how can I get the row-index (position) of an element by id

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

How do you get the row-index (position) of a row by the id in an ExtJS GridPanel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use [store.indexOf](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-indexOf) method:

```js
var record = store.getNodeById(id),
    rowIndex = store.indexOf(record);
```

Comment: To get a record in Ext4 use `store.getAt()`.

Comment: @A1rPun store.getAt() requires the row index as argument. Which is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 6):

[`Ext.data.Store.indexOfId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-indexOfId)

```
var rowIndex = store.indexOfId(id);
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer and should be the accepted one.